# Update only duplicate values in a table column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

[image: update field in query access with duplicate field]

I have got a table that has a column with duplicate values. I would like to update duplicate values (not the first instance though) by incrementing by 1 so that I can get rid of duplicates in that column.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I answered your question this time, but the rule in this forum is that you try something yourself first and show where you have a problem and then members try to help you. Please consult this page for more information on how to use this site and ask questions etc: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

You need ranking on Tel over username. This will give you the ranking.

```
SELECT *, (select count(table1.username) 
from table1 as tbl2 
where table1.tel >= tbl2.tel and table1.username=tbl2.username)
as rank from table1 ORDER BY username,tel;
```

if your active column is always T then you can hard code it in the query as below:

```
SELECT *, (select count(table1.username) from
table1 as tbl2 
where table1.tel >= tbl2.tel and table1.username=tbl2.username) & 'T' 
as rank from table1 ORDER BY username,tel
```

if column active in Table1 can be different, then save the first query as query1 and use this join query:

```
SELECT Table1.active & query1.rank AS Expr1, Table1.tel, Table1.username
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Query1 ON Table1.ID = Query1.ID;
```

add an ID column to your Table1 if you don't have one.

Comment: This syntax will not work in Access SQL which uses `UPDATE ... JOIN` and requires *updateable* queries which aggregate queries are not.